# jQuery serialize form update MySQL based on form ID?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, serialization

I populate a list of `<form>` using a PHP while loop, and fill the fields with values from MySQL. Now I want to be able to update all forms with one `submit`- button.

The form looks something like this in HTML (note, on my actual page there are multiple like this. The only thing that differes is the `<form id='X'>`:

```
<form id='34' name='customercontact' method='post' action='customerUpdate.php'>
    Förnamn: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_firstname' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    Efternamn: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_lastname' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    Telefonnummer: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_phone' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    Mobiltelefon: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_cellphone' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    E-mail: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_email' class='textbox' value='text....'>
        <select name='isActive'>
            <option value="0" selected>Inaktiv</option>
            <option value="1">Aktiv</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

How do I use jQuery serialize to send each form and all the values as a string? I don'r really know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all forms on the page `$('form')` and then iterate through them and 'submit' values via AJAX.

**UPDATE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customer_contact_save').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
        $.each($('form'), function(index) { 
            var sData = $(this).serialize(); // get data from form for submit
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",// path to php script that saves data to db
                url: "some.php",
                data: sData,
                success: function(someMessageFromPhp) {
                    alert(someMessageFromPhp); // alert to user what some.php returned
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should expand your answer or delete it and leave it as comment because it's not really helpful.

Comment: @Zagor23 Yes, I understand I can do that. But how?

Comment: @N.B. I have expanded my answer. Hope that helps now.

Comment: Thank you for the update! It now runs through my forms however the POST data is empty... Any thoughts on that?

Comment: `.serialize()` returns a query-string encoded version of the form values. You should replace this with `.serializeArray()` to get an array back instead, which will work properly with `$.ajax`.

Comment: @JimO'Brien I tried that. But the POST data is still empty (using FireBug)

Comment: Hmm I tried this code through firebug on couple of sites and it always catch all forms all the form values... I forgot about preventing submit in my answer, now I added that row too `e.preventDeafault`.

Comment: @Zagor23 Hello and thank's for taking your time. I am getting this error in Firebug: `XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({length:1, 0:({}), context:({}), selector:"#customer_contact_save"})`

Comment: @David Sorry, I forgot to call `live` with event click (facepalm). I've changed third line of my answer to `$('#customer_contact_save').live('click', function(e){`

Comment: @Zagor23 Yeah, I noticed your updates. I don't get any errors now but the POST data is still empty.. Perhaps there is something wrong with my forms?

Comment: Try `console.log(sData);` inside each, after declaring and you will get value of sData in firebug's console tab. You should get something like `contact_firstname=first&contact_lastname=text....&contact_phone=text....&contact_cellphone=text....&contact_email=text....&isActive=0` If everything is ok there, try `var_dump($_POST);` in your php script to see what you get in php.

Comment: @Zagor23 FireBug returns `(an empty string)` `var_dump($_POST);` is empty also.

Comment: I have created a new Question ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506093/jquery-form-serialize-empty-post-data-on-submit)). I'll close this question. Thank's again @Zagor23 for taking your time!