# jQuery form serialize empty POST data on submit

Tags: jquery, serialization, post

I populate multiple forms in a PHP loop with and differs them with `<form id='X'>` 
They look something like this in HTML:

```
<form id='34' class='customer_contact' name='customercontact' method='post' action='customerUpdate.php'>
    Förnamn: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_firstname' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    Efternamn: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_lastname' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    Telefonnummer: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_phone' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    Mobiltelefon: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_cellphone' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    E-mail: <br /><input type='text' name='contact_email' class='textbox' value='text....'>
    <select name='isActive'>
        <option value="0" selected>Inaktiv</option>
        <option value="1">Aktiv</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And I try to serialize them using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#customer_contact_save').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each($('form.customer_contact'), function(index) { 
        var sData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updateCustomer.php",
            data: sData,
            success: function(someMessageFromPhp) {
                alert(someMessageFromPhp); 
            }
        });
    });
  });
});
```

*(Thank's to Zagor23 on SO for that code)*

**But my `POST` data is empty** (I am using FireBug to see what is beeing sent).

I tried adding `console.log(sData);` in the script but FireBug returns: `(an empty string)` and php `var_dump($_POST);` is empty also..

Anyone got an idea on what is wrong?

Comment: is there only one empty ajax call or number of calls is equal to number of forms ?

Comment: @shershen number of calls is equal to number of forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a fiddle i've made of your code - http://jsfiddle.net/7Y9vn/
if you turn firebug on and press the button you'll see both request are runing ok, so you should probably search for an error other code o the page

Answer (score 8):

It turned out that in my actual code i forgot to add `name` to my input fields (facepalm).

Thank's anyway!

Comment: I was about to post it but saw your post. So I'm voting this one up.

Comment: So dumb ! I did same mistake as I forgot my basics :) You saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this?

```
$(".customer_contact").each(function()
{ 
    var form_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var sData = $("#" + form_id).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateCustomer.php",
        data: sData,
        success: function(someMessageFromPhp) {
            alert(someMessageFromPhp); 
        }
    });
});
```